# Images look extremely small in Samsung galaxy S7

Tags: android, xml

In my app i fetch images from JSON and display it in a gallery. On clicking each image it expands to a full activity and it looks normally like this.
[Pic one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyfep.jpg)

But when i tested it on Galaxy S7 Edge , the individual image looked tiny and i dont if its with Nougat.

[Pic Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BydiG.jpg)

how can i solve this problem.

im posting my code

```
public class Displaydemo extends FragmentActivity {

static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
static int pos ;
Button Img_Sel;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
public static String sel_img;

ImageFragmentPagerAdapter imageFragmentPagerAdapter;
ViewPager viewPager;
public static RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
public static ImageLoader mImageLoader;
public static NetworkImageView niv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displaydemo);
    NUM_ITEMS= getIntent().getIntExtra("count",0);
    pos=getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0);
    getImageLoader();
    Img_Sel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Img_select);

    imageFragmentPagerAdapter = new ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerdemo);

    viewPager.setAdapter(imageFragmentPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

}

public static class ImageFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public static int p=0;
    public ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        p=position;
        SwipeFragment fragment = new SwipeFragment();
        return SwipeFragment.newInstance(p);
    }
}

public static class SwipeFragment extends Fragment {
    public static NetworkImageView imgNetWorkView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View swipeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_fragment, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        imgNetWorkView = (NetworkImageView) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.imgNetwork);

        int position = bundle.getInt("position");
        final String imgResId= Datas.imageIds[position];

      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),imgResId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        imgNetWorkView.setImageUrl(imgResId, mImageLoader);

        Displaydemo.sel_img=""+position;
        String imgsel = imgResId;


        imgNetWorkView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GalleryActivity.class);
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                String ur = null;
                ur =imgResId;
                args.putString("URL", ur);
                intent.putExtras(args);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return swipeView;
    }
    static SwipeFragment newInstance(int position) {
        SwipeFragment swipeFragment = new SwipeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", position);
        swipeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return swipeFragment;
    }
}
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:gravity="center">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pagerdemo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: use: android:scaleType="fitXY"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` property for `ImageView` which is displaying images on `ViewPager`.
and make width of that `ImageView` to `match_parent`.